# javnumber generator

Tags: javascript

I've tried var p1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100); but i'm not sure how to integrate that into the code

Comment: `client.say(\`Your random number is ${p1}\``?

Comment: That doesn't work, it just says ${p1} in chat.

Comment: Are you using the backticks?

Comment: No, but i just tried with them and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you use `console.log` to check that any output is working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random number generator for Node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42023200/random-number-generator-for-node-js)

Comment: OK. What is the library/API you're using which has the client object, with `say` and `on` as methods?

Answer (score 1):

While I don't know the client.say function, try this

```
client.say(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100)+"");
```

Comment: What doesn't work? How is it not working? Is there an error?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get a random number:

```
 var xname = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
```

Comment: Could you integrate that into the script i posted above please?

Comment: @TomWilson Are you not able to?

Comment: Sorry, i'm not able to.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Would you be able to for me please?

Comment: We've already tried, but you've said our suggestions don't work. Can you follow my suggestion and use `console.log` to help and figure out what's wrong?

Comment: @evolutionxbox It's for Twitch.tv. It literally just says Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100) in the chat instead of putting a random number instead.

Comment: See that's the kind of information which needs to be put in the question.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Sorry about that man, are you still able to help me?

Comment: Can you post the code you're using when you try out our suggestions?

Comment: @evolutionxbox var canSendMessage = true;
client.on('chat', function(channel, user, message, self) {
if(message === "!random" && canSendMessage ) {
canSendMessage = false;
client.say("shred", "(Math.floor(Math.random()*100))");
setTimeout(function(){ canSendMessage = true }, 2000);
}});

Comment: It's because you're turning the function calls into a string. Change `client.say("shred", "(Math.floor(Math.random()*100))");` to `client.say("shred", Math.floor(Math.random()*100));`

Comment: @evolutionxbox It gives me this error. /Users/Tom/node_modules/tmi.js/lib/commands.js:291
        if ((message.startsWith(".") && !message.startsWith("..")) || message.startsWith("/") || message.startsWith("\\")) {